# Setting annotated field value using reflection in generic class. (IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, generics, reflection, annotations

I have been facing an issue that implies Reflection, Annotations and Generics in Java. I have a class that creates a new instance of a generic type called `B`. Then it will search for any `Field` with the `MyCustomAnnotation` annotation and sets its value to a determined one.

The class that does this is:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class MyInstanceCreator<B> {
    
    private final String myValue = "Hello world!";
    
    public B createInstance(Class<B> classType) throws NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        B obj = classType.getConstructor().newInstance();
        for(Field f: classType.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if(f.isAnnotationPresent(MyCustomAnnotation.class)) {
                System.out.println("Is annotated!");
                updateField(obj, f);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
    
    private void updateField(B instance, Field field) throws IllegalAccessException {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(myValue, instance);
        field.setAccessible(false);
    }
    
}
```

The annotation class:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {}
```

The custom type has an annotated Field of type `String`:

```java
public class MyCustomType {
    
    @MyCustomAnnotation
    private String value;
    
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
}
```

Finally my main class is:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            MyInstanceCreator<MyCustomType> iCreator = new MyInstanceCreator<>();
            MyCustomType myObj = iCreator.createInstance(MyCustomType.class);
            System.out.println(myObj.getValue());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the program is:

```java
Is annotated!

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field MyCustomType.value to java.lang.String
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:780)
    at MyInstanceCreator.updateField(MyInstanceCreator.java:21)
    at MyInstanceCreator.createInstance(MyInstanceCreator.java:13)
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:5)
```

It does not make any sense to me why reflection cannot assign a `java.lang.String` value to a `java.lang.String` field as the `IllegalArgumentException` message says. I must be missing something but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem…

```
...
field.set(myValue, instance);
...
```

[*Here's your fix*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/7G)…

```
...
field.set(instance, myValue);
...
```

[*Here are the docs*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object))…

> *public void set​(Object obj, Object value)*…
>
> ...
>
> *Parameters:*
>
> *obj - the object whose field should be modified*
>
> *value - the new value for the field of obj being modified*
>
> …

Comment: No you're not dumb. Because if you're dumb, then I'm dumb too. Haha. I also didn't see what was wrong until after trying two or three less simple fixes. If, like me, you haven't used that _`Field.set(Object, Object)`_ method a lot, it's easy to mixup which _`Object`_ param is which. So don't sweat it :)